# Fréchet derivative of $ \varphi:\mathbb R^q \to \mathbb R, g \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n \langle g-b_i, a_i\rangle^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, frechet-derivative

Fix $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb R^q$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$. Consider the map
$$
\varphi:\mathbb R^q \to \mathbb R, g \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n \langle g-b_i, a_i\rangle^2.
$$
I would like to compute the Fréchet derivative of $\varphi$. Could you have a check on my attempt?

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Comment: Yes $ $$ $$ $$ $

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification @CalvinKhor. Can we go further to compute the second-order derivative or Hessian matrix?

Comment: Yes. In fact your derivative is a linear map so the second derivative ‘is itself’ suitably interpreted (the same way you did the first derivative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{n=1}^N s_n^2$ where
$s_n=\mathbf{a}_n:(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}_n)$.

Taking differential yields
$ds_n = \mathbf{a}_n:d\mathbf{x}$, and thus
$$ d\phi 
= \sum_{n=1}^N 2 s_n ds_n
= \left[ \sum_{n=1}^N 2 s_n \mathbf{a}_n \right]:d\mathbf{x}
$$
It follows
$
d\phi(\mathbf{x})[\mathbf{v}]
= \left[ 2 \sum_{n=1}^N s_n \mathbf{a}_n \right]:\mathbf{v}
$.

Write the gradient as
$\mathbf{g}=2\sum_{n=1}^N s_n \mathbf{a}_n$
Taking the differential yields the Hessian
\begin{eqnarray}
d\mathbf{g} 
&=& 2 \sum_{n=1}^N (ds_n) \mathbf{a}_n \\
&=& \color{red}{2 \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf{a}_n \mathbf{a}_n^T} d\mathbf{x} 
= \color{red}{\mathbf{H}} d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

First, we consider the map $F(g):= \langle g, a\rangle$. Because $F$ is linear continuous, we have $\partial F(g) = F$ and thus $\partial F (g)[v] = \langle v, a\rangle$ for all $g,v \in \mathbb R^q$. Second, consider the map $G(g) := (F(g)-\alpha)^2$. By chain rule,
$$
\partial G(g)[v] =2(F(g)-\alpha) \langle v, a\rangle.
$$

It follows that
$$
\partial \varphi(g)[v] = 2\sum_{i=1}^n \langle g-b_i, a_i\rangle \langle v, a_i\rangle.
$$